# Rails - update_column and ActiveRecord enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I require to use `update_column` in my Rails application to prevent callbacks from being run. I have my ActiveRecord model with enum:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum state: [:not_used, :used]
end
```

In normal scenario (i.e. when I do want the callbacks to run) I can use something like that:

```
@car.update_attribute :state, :not_used
```

Is it possible to do something similar with `update_column`?

I am using **Rails 4.2**

Comment: I think you have to change the variant name `:new` to other name since it causes ArgumentError.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`update_column` doesn't recognize symbols as a variant of the enum. I think that you have to Use `Car.states[:not_used]` instead of `:not_used`. Like this:

```
@car.update_column :state, Car.states[:not_used]
```